# SwiftUI: Creating own data types and work with them. How?

Tags: xcode, struct, swiftui

currently I am programming my first own app in SwiftUI. I want to create a custom datatype called "Exercise". For this I have created a struct:

```
struct Exercise: Identifiable { 
    var id = UUID()
    var name: String = ""
    var description: String?
}
```

Also I have a class with different data where I have created a instance of that struct in form of an array:

```
var exercise: [Exercise] = []
```

Now I want to append to these array with a new element in a different view where I have a textfield for the name of the Exercise and a textfield for the description. But I don't know how I can do this. Can anybody help me?

Thanks in advance and sorry for my English :)

EDIT:
Code with the View where I want to append a new element to the class with the Array "exercise":

```
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        VStack(spacing: 20){
            
            Text("Name")
                .alignmentNewExercise()
                .font(.title)
            
            TextField(placeholder, text: $newExercise)
                .alignmentNewExercise()
                .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
            
            TextField("Description", text: $description)
                .alignmentNewExercise()
                .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
            
            Button(action: {
                exercise.name = newExercise
                exercise.description = description


                
                //data.exercise.append(...) **here I want to add the new element to the array in the class "data", but I don't know how**
                
                newExercise = ""
            }) {
                Text("Hinzufügen")
            }
            .disabled(validExercise)
            
            Spacer()
        }
        .navigationBarTitle("Neue Übung")
        .navigationBarItems(trailing:
            Button(action: {
                self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
            }) {
                Text("Zurück")
            })
    }
}
```

The class with the array:

```
class Daten: ObservableObject{

     @Published var exercise: [Exercise] = []
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To append new data you can create a new `Exercise` and add it to your collection:

```
let exercise = Exercise(name: self.newExercise, description: self.description)
data.exercise.append(exercise)
```

Which can be shortened to:

```
data.exercise.append(Exercise(name: self.newExercise, description: self.description))
```

Also try using *plural* names for your collections:

```
@Published var exercises: [Exercise] = []
```

It indicates it's a collection and not a single object.

Comment: I made some changes and now it works! Thank you : )

Answer (score 0):

You should pass an instance of `Daten` around. Here I used a singleton object for it as a shared instance:

```
class Daten: ObservableObject{
    static let shared = Daten()
    @Published var exercise: [Exercise] = []
}
```

then you can access it and change the value like any other array in Swift:

```
Button("Hinzufügen") {
    let exercise = Exercise(
        name: self.newExercise,
        description: self.description)

    Daten.shared.exercise.append(exercise)
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you don't *normally* need singletons in SwiftUI. There usually is a better way to pass data. In the question here I don't see a point for using a singleton (unless OP provides more data).

Comment: I didn’t want to explain how to pass dat in this answer since this isn’t the main point of the original question. But you are right! Thanks for making it clear.

Comment: Thanks Mojtaba, it worked... in some way. When I press enter and I print the array in the "Add exercise view" I can see the new exercise. I also show these exercises in a list but there it doesn't work. The array is empty. Any ideas?

Comment: To make it work in a list, you may first put it in a State variable.

Comment: Or `@ObservedObject`. I didn’t explain because there where no lists in the question. You should consider asking a new question on for new context of this one

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Now it works with pawello's solution